# Não esta fazendo o fragment replace

Tags: android, android-fragment, asynctask

Olá, eu tenho uma app que assim quando é acessado carrega um feed, inicializando um AsyncTask, porem se o usuário apertar em uma das opções do drawer antes da Task terminar, a app não da o replace e trava, fica o progressBar girando e nada acontece e como se o ele se perdesse.

Assim que a app é aberta ele adiciona o fragment:

```
Fragment_Main fragmentMain = new Fragment_Main();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_main,fragmentMain,"fragmentMain");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Onde inicia a task:

```
updateFeedTask = new UpdateFeedTask(swipeRefreshLayout, getActivity(), Fragment_Main.this);
updateFeedTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Porem se o usuário clicar por exemplo no pesquisar e se a task acima ainda nao estiver sido finalizada, nada mais acontece na app, nem crash acontece.

O código abaixo é uma das opções que o usuario pode selecionar antes da task acabar, acontecendo o problema:

```
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(Fragment_Main.updateFeedTask != null) {
                Fragment_Main.updateFeedTask.cancel(true);
            }

            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentMain");

            if (fragment != null){
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
            }

            Fragment_SearchActivity fragmentSearchActivity = Fragment_SearchActivity.newInstance(searchView);
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragmentSearchActivity, "fragmentSearchActivity");
            ft.addToBackStack("back");
            ft.commit();
            if (!isDrawerLocked) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListOptions);
            }
        }
    });
```

Abaixo a implementação do AsyncTask

```
public class UpdateFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, FeedCardAdapter> {

private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
private Activity activity;
private DelegateFeed delegateFeed;

public UpdateFeedTask(SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout, Activity activity, DelegateFeed delegateFeed) {
    this.swipeRefreshLayout = swipeRefreshLayout;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.delegateFeed = delegateFeed;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
}

@Override
protected FeedCardAdapter doInBackground(Void... params) {
    List<Obj> objList = new ObjDAO().getMyFeed();
    return new FeedCardAdapter(objList , R.layout.feed, activity, delegateFeed);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(FeedCardAdapter feedCardAdapter) {
    delegateFeed.setFeedCardAdapter(feedCardAdapter);
}
```

}

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Obrigado

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Sem postar seu código, como vamos te ajudar? Clique em [edit] e adicione o código onde está dando o problema.

Comment: Obrigado Diego, ja editei.

Comment: @EricRosa, tem como você postar a implementação do seu **AsyncTask**?

Comment: Postado @regmoraes

Comment: Tente implementar o método onCancelled() no seu async. Ele é acionado quando a ação do async é cancelada, no seu caso pelo clique do usuário